# Card popup on avatar hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI's Avatar component, I have incorporated a card component on avatar hover. I cant seem to get the hover to work while hovering on the avatar, the hover seems to be visible without even hovering. Some guidance would be appreciated.

```
import { Avatar, Card, CardContent, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import { Container } from '@mui/system';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

export const Test = (): ReactElement => {
  const users = [{ login: 'sally' }, { login: 'john' }];

  return (
    <>
      <Container sx={{ display: 'flex', direction: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center', border: 'solid 1px', p: 2 }}>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <div key={user.login} style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: 10 }}>
            <Avatar
              alt={`Badge photo for ${user.login}`}
              src={`https://mywebpage?uid=${user.login}`}
              sx={{ height: 40, width: 40, m: 2 }}
            />
            <Card
              sx={{
                height: '400px',
                width: '500px',
                ':hover': {
                  boxShadow: 20,
                },
              }}>
              <CardContent>
                <Typography>{user.login}</Typography>
              </CardContent>
            </Card>
          </div>
        ))}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Error you are getting because of this:

```
return (
    <>...</>
    <div>...</div> 
)
```

in JSX you need to return only one element you need to wrap all codes in one element like this:

```
return (
    <>...</>
)
```

if you want to show Card component on Avatar hovering you can use state with mouse events

```
export const Test = (): any => {
  const users = [{ login: 'john' }, { login: 'sally' }];
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false);

  const handleMouseOver = () => {
    setIsHovering(true);
  };

  const handleMouseOut = () => {
    setIsHovering(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Container sx={{ display: 'flex', direction: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center', border: 'solid 1px', p: 2 }}>
        {users.map((user) => (
          <Avatar
            key={user.login}
            alt={`Badge photo for ${user.login}`}
            src={`https://myimage?id=${user.login}`}
            sx={{ height: 40, width: 40, m: 1, borderRadius: '50%' }}
             onMouseOver={handleMouseOver}
          onMouseOut={handleMouseOut}
          />
         {isHovering && (
             <Card
         sx={{
            ':hover': {
            boxShadow: 20,
            },
         }}>

          <Avatar
            key={user.login}
            alt={`Badge photo for ${user.login}`}
            src={`https://myimage?id=${user.login}`}
            sx={{ height: 40, width: 40, m: 1, borderRadius: '50%' }}
          />
           </Card>
        )}
        ))}
      </Container>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Hi, I had something similar, but if you close off the users.map too early then user.login is undefined. How do I reference the appropriate key when outside the loop?

Comment: Sorry my bad now I have edited

Comment: I am getting the error:  )' expected around {isHovering &&